# linux + increase swap memory

Tags: linux

from my linux machine swap is - 0 why , and how to increase the swap?

```
  [root@my_small_linux free

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

 Mem:       8172212    2087904    6084308          0     270020    1376776

-/+ buffers/cache:     441108    7731104

Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: Why? As it stands this system is a long way from needing any swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means, that no swap partition is available. If you have some unused space on hard drive, you can make it a swap partition (via fdisk). Or you can make swap on file. This creates 2GB swap:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1048576 count=2048
mkswap /swap
swapon /swap
```

And add it to /etc/fstab to be mounted at boot.

Comment: I not get anything by swapon -s ?

Comment: Okay, you did all 3 commands and `swapon -s` says nothing? Please send result of `ls -lh /swap`. That will show how the swap file is created. By the way, you have to do this under root or via `sudo`.

Comment: @Mkudlacek how to build disk partition for swap?

Comment: As MrShunz showed - via fdisk create partition with id "swap". You can use free space or old unused partition. Then execute mkswap on /dev/sd.. and prepare this partition to be a swap. Turn on the swap via swapon /dev/sd.. and add it /etc/fstab as MrShunz showed.

Comment: how to uninstall the swap procedure according to your example

Comment: `swapoff -a` turns off all swaps.

Comment: @mkudiacek please give me example how to swap on partition in place on directory

Answer (score 0):

Could also be that in your `/etc/fstab` the swap partition is listed by `uuid` instead of `/dev/sd*`. If for some reason the uuid changed, it cannot be automatically mounted.

Check with `fdisk -l` as root/with sudo if it lists some swap partions. My output is:

```
[snip]

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          34      273073+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb2              35        1340    10490445   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3            1341        1449      875542+  82  Linux swap / Solaris <<--- here it is!
/dev/sdb4            1450        9729    66509100   83  Linux
```

and then check the symbolik link to UUID with: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`. Im my case:

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2011-03-08 08:39 3565be89-f1fe-478c-9653-a1dbeb9406a9 -> ../../sdb3
```

So in `/etc/fstab` I have:

```
UUID=3565be89-f1fe-478c-9653-a1dbeb9406a9       none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Disclaimer**: i'm under Ubuntu now, so actual paths might be different under other distros.